# ggplot2: Boxplots with points and fill separation

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data which can be divaded via two seperators. One is year and second is a field characteristics.

```
box<-as.data.frame(1:36)

box$year <- c(1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,
              1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,
              1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,
              1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997)
box$year <- as.character(box$year)

box$case <- c(6.40,6.75,6.11,6.33,5.50,5.40,5.83,4.57,5.80,
              6.00,6.11,6.40,7.00,NA,5.44,6.00,  NA,6.00,
              6.00,6.20,6.40,6.64,6.33,6.60,7.14,6.89,7.10,
              6.73,6.27,6.64,6.41,6.42,6.17,6.05,5.89,5.82)

box$code <- c("L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L",
              "L","L","L","L","L","L","M","M","M","M","M","M",
              "M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M")

colour <- factor(box$code, labels = c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4"))
```

In boxplots, I want to display points over them, to see how data is distributed. That is easily done with one single boxplot for every year:

```
ggplot(box, aes(x = year, y = case, fill = "#F8766D")) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.80) +
  geom_point(colour = colour, size = 5) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

But it become more complicated as I add fill parameter in them:

```
ggplot(box, aes(x = year, y = case, fill = code)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.80) +
  geom_point(colour = colour, size = 5) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

And now the question: How to move these points to boxplot axes, where they belong? As blue points to blue boxplot and red to red one.

Comment: [`geom_dotplot`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_dotplot.html) using `binaxis = 'y'` may also be of interest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like Henrik said, use `position_jitterdodge()` and `shape = 21`.  You can clean up your code a bit too:

1. No need to define box, then fill it piece by piece
2. You can let `ggplot` hash out the colors if you wish and skip constructing the colors factor. If you want to change the defaults, look into `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual`.

   ```
   box <- data.frame(year = c(1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,
                     1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,
                     1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,
                     1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997),
                     case  = c(6.40,6.75,6.11,6.33,5.50,5.40,5.83,4.57,5.80,
                     6.00,6.11,6.40,7.00,NA,5.44,6.00,  NA,6.00,
                     6.00,6.20,6.40,6.64,6.33,6.60,7.14,6.89,7.10,
                     6.73,6.27,6.64,6.41,6.42,6.17,6.05,5.89,5.82),
                     code = c("L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L",
                     "L","L","L","L","L","L","M","M","M","M","M","M",
                     "M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M"))

   ggplot(box, aes(x = factor(year), y = case, fill = code)) +
     geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.80) +
     geom_point(aes(fill = code), size = 5, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge()) +
     theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
           axis.title.x = element_blank(),
           axis.title.y = element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
           panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
           legend.position = "none")
   ```

[image]

Comment: What is the black point on the left of the lowest circle in 1997?

Comment: A point/potential outlier from `geom_boxlot`

Comment: If add a group to change the dot shape, it seems not work anymore...

Answer (score 6):

I see you've already accepted @JakeKaupp's nice answer, but I thought I would throw in a different option, using [`geom_dotplot`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_dotplot.html). The data you are visualizing is rather small, so why not forego the boxplot?

```
ggplot(box, aes(x = factor(year), y = case, fill = code))+
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center',
                 position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But my dataset is qutie big, so I have to use boxplots. The set for this question is only a little piece of it.